# How to deploy application which uses pybind11?

Tags: pybind11

I know pybind11 provides a way to call Python from C++. My question is, how can I distribute the application? For example, does user still need to install Python and Python packages on their machine?

I wish that if I use pybind11 , I can just put used Python scripts under my app folder, and called from C++. User doesn't need to install Python at all on his machine.  Can pybind11 achieve this goal?  Or can Python/C API or Boost.Python do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to install python. All of those packages, and ones like it, are [language bindings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding) between C++ and Python. Say you'd like to use a Python script in your C++ project and so you made some bindings for the Python script using Pybind11. When you run your C++ code, it'll use parts of the Python script which will be run in Python. What Pybind11 allows you to do is translate the input to and the output from the Python script, it does not reimplement it.